# Relativistic kinematics - decay

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, standard-model, pions

I'm struggling to solve this problem in relativistic kinematics:

> $D$ meson decays to $\pi$ and $K$. After a while, the kaon decays to $\pi^0$ and $\pi^-$. If the $\pi^0$ moves vertecally to $K^-$ in the $D$ meson rest system, what is the energy of $\pi^0$ in this system? Assume that $\pi^0$ , $\pi^-$ have the same mass.

Let me be more specific:

One can calculate the the energy and the momentum of the kaon , and by doing so, i can write the matrix transform from the rest frame of the kaon to the D meson (by assuming the kaon moves in the x axis) , and of course the inverse transform by adding minus sign to the momentum term.

At the same time we can derive the  energy of the pion in the rest frame of the kaon by using energy and momentum conservation.

By assuming the pion moves in the y axis relative to the rest frame of the D meson i can write its 4 vector of momentum energy in general form, and by using the inverse matrix transform i wrote for the kaon , one can calculate the 4 vector of the pion in the kaon rest frame.

After all, we can compare the first and the last teem of the energies and by doing so, to extract the energy term of the pion in the D meson rest frame.

But after i plug all the numbers i get less energy from the pion invariant mass. Is it possible?

Sorry i didn't add  any detail before...

Comment: Sorry i didn't add any details, i edited my question

Comment: I think it is a bit unfair to flag the OP for not showing some efforts. Fair enough, he did not make the effort to typeset his equations but he did work the exercise through, as it is clear from his last question, and the comment to my answer, in a way that was way too much work in fact!

Answer (score 2):

You have lost yourself with all these Lorentz transformations. Here is how I would approach the problem. In the following the symbols $p$ denote 3-momenta, the symbols $E$, energies, and $m_{\pi}$ the mass assumed to be common to all the pions.

First, using the conservation of energy and momentum for $D\to\pi K$, in the rest frame of $D$ as rightly suggested, you can compute $E_\pi$ and $E_K$: this is classic, I'll let you do that and assume we know those energies in the following.

Then,

$$\begin{align}
E_K &= E_{\pi^0}+E_{\pi^-}\tag{1}\\
p_K &= p_{\pi^0}+p_{\pi^-}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From (2),

$$p_{\pi^-}^2=p_K^2+p_{\pi^0}^2-2\underbrace{p_K\cdot p_{\pi^0}}_{0\text{ by hypothesis}}$$

So the quantity you are asked to compute can now be written

$$E_{\pi^0}^2=m_\pi^2+p_{\pi^0}^2=\underbrace{m_\pi^2+p_{\pi^-}^2}_{E_{\pi^-}^2}\underbrace{-p_K^2}_{m_K^2-E_K^2}$$

But with (1),

$$E_{\pi^-}^2=(E_K - E_{\pi^0})^2$$

and we have now an equation to solve for $E_{\pi^0}$,

$$E_{\pi^0}^2=(E_K - E_{\pi^0})^2 + m_K^2-E_K^2$$

since everything else is known. Importantly, it should be noted that this statement would still hold when $p_K\cdot p_{\pi^0}\neq 0$, since this scalar product could be expressed with $E_K$, $E_{\pi^0}$ and an angle. Hence this method is general. Anyway, here cancellations make the equation trivial:

$$E_{\pi^0} = \frac{m_K^2}{2E_K}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got exactly the same answer as you did but if you plug the numbers, the energy you get for pion zero is less then its rest energy. How can it be?

Comment: I get $E_{\pi^0}=139.37$ MeV if using $m_\pi=m_{\pi^0}$, and 139.32 MeV if using $m_{\pi^\pm}$, and then $m_{\pi^0}=134.98$ MeV. There is no problem, is there?